# Server sent events + Java with Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring-mvc

I am currently having a problem related to SSE and Windows XP. The source code below is currently working in every Chrome I tried except for Chrome in Windows XP (?) Not sure why. This is intended to be used for a control panel, where users **must** use Chrome. In other words, I don't care about IE, Firefox, etc.

**The problem**: Server side events works everywhere (Chrome) but not in Windows XP (Chrome). **When I say it works, I mean that the message handler is called.**

**The code**

- Javascript code

  ```
  if (!!window.EventSource) {
     console.log("Event source available");
     var source = new EventSource('/admin/systemalert');

     source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
          console.log(e.data);
     });

     source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
          console.log("Connection was opened.");
     }, false);

     source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
          if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
              console.log("Connection was closed.");
          } else {
              console.log(e.readyState);    <-- in windows XP it prints Error here
          }
     }, false);
  } else {
          console.log("No SSE available");
  }
  ```
- Server side code

  ```
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/admin/**")
  public class AdminController {

          @RequestMapping("systemalert")
          public @ResponseBody String sendMessage(HttpServletResponse response) {
                  Random r = new Random();
                  response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
                  try {
                          Thread.sleep(10000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                  }   
                  return "data:Testing 1,2,3" + r.nextInt() +"\n";
          }

  }
  ```

As stated in the code, the line console.log(e.readyState); prints "Error" when using Chrome in Windows XP. Any ideas? Anyone see anything wrong with the source code?

Thanks in advance.
Agustin

Comment: Are you sure that the version of Chrome you have installed on XP is the same as the other versions where the code succeeds?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `response.setContentType("text/event-stream");`? Maybe this content type is not recognised on XP?

Comment: If I remove that i get EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone with this problem, the problem was related to the new lines needed after the data. Basically, you need two lines and not one as I was using. That way it works everywhere.

Changing this:

```
return "data:Testing 1,2,3" + r.nextInt() +"\n";
```

To this:

```
return "data:Testing 1,2,3" + r.nextInt() +"\n\n";
```

Fixes the problem..

Answer (score 6):

Instead of implementing manually SSE, be aware that Spring Framework 4.2+ supports [natively SSE](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-async-sse). See [this sample SSE enabled controller](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-react-isomorphic/blob/master/src/main/java/io/spring/isomorphic/CommentController.java#L73) returning an [SseEmitter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/SseEmitter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have created a small example in PHP + HTML5.

You can take a look at it [here](http://arancione-consulting.com/server-events/). You will see that I have two different buttons; one to create the event source and the second one to disconnect it.

The code prints directly to firefox/chrome console. As you will see, the message handler is called in firefox but not chrome.

**This is not working on any chrome I tested so far.**

Example Firefox output:

```
Creating event source
Open
Id: 1334072077
Message: Se puede leer esto?
Origin: http://arancione-consulting.com
Closed
Open
Id: 1334072082
Message: Se puede leer esto?
Origin: http://arancione-consulting.com
Closed
```

Example Chrome output:

```
Creating event source
Open
Closed
Open
Closed
```

In case anyone wants to know, the server side code is:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // prevent caching of event data.
echo "id: " . time() . "\n";
echo "Event: time\n";
echo "data: Se puede leer esto?\n";
flush();
?>
```

Any ideas?